# What is Me!something in VBA

Tags: vba

I was reading through some old VB and I saw something like this

```
Dim ID As Double
Me!ID = Null
```

I know `Me.ID` is like `this.ID` in other languages, but I have never seen `!`

Comment: http://bytecomb.com/the-bang-exclamation-operator-in-vba/

Answer (score 1):

in VB6 (and I think in VB5 too) you can use "!" instead of "field()" when you use a recordset:

```
opEstado(0).value = rsDatos!Valida
```

Is the same that:

```
opEstado(0).value = rsDatos.Fields("Valida")
```

Or, in your case:

```
Me.Fields("ID") = Null
```

Bye.